# Is there an equivalent to /etc/permissions with support for ACL?

Tags: permissions, acl, chkconfig

I need to define a list of rights with standard UNIX and some with ACL rights.
Is there a way to do check that with a config file like `/etc/permissions` does for UNIX rights?

It is a file that is provided and used by the SUSE specific [permissions package](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Security_Documentation#The_permissions_Package) that controls the privilege settings for a number of global system files and security sensitive package files in the distribution. It is concerned with the following kinds of file or directory based privileges:

- the classical UNIX file owner and group assignment of a file.
- the classical UNIX user/group/world access bits.
- special file mode bits like the setuid and setgid bit or the sticky bit.
- capability bits.

The structure of these files is line based and each non-comment line has the format:

```
/path/to/file    <owner>:<group>    <octal-mode>
```

- <sub>Each line could be extended by an additional following line that defines the Linux capabilities of the file.</sub>

Comment: Welcome here! I think you're referring to something that used to exist, on Novell UnixWare (I'm not sure it still exists), maybe on some other SRV4 derivatives. In any case, it's not a common thing, as far as I can tell, so you'll *have* to tell us which actual UNIX operating system you're referring to. I cannot find information that /etc/permissions exists on a system where ACLs also exist, but that might just be my lack of access to documentation.

Comment: **On second reading of your question**; you're not asking about a system that actually uses /etc/permissions. ah! You're just looking for a tool that checks permissions against a recorded set of "correct" permissions from some config file!